# How to Override a Exception class methods in JAVA

Tags: java, exception, overriding

I am using a private JAVA library in my project. In the library API, developers wrote a custom Exception class "ClassException" and if any exception raises they throw this class exception object. At some point of view I couldn't figure out clearly where the exception is raised when using this library in my project. All I could see on the console as 
`ClassException raised inside a java class Demo` of the private library.

I don't have the source code of the library to change as per my wish. All I can see is the .class file.

**ClassException:**

```
    public class ClassException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private ClassErrorStatus mErrorCode;

    public ClassException(ClassErrorStatus pErrorCode) {

    }

    public ClassException(String pMessage, ClassErrorStatus pErrorCode) {

    }

    public ClassException(Throwable pCause, ClassErrorStatus pErrorCode) {

    }

    public ClassException(String pMessage, Throwable pCause, ClassErrorStatus pErrorCode) {

    }

    public ClassErrorStatus getErrorStatus() {

    }
}
```

How can I override this class methods such that if anywhere a ClassException is thrown it should call my custom class exception methods. Is there anyway to do so?

Like `throw new ClassException()` should call my own Exception class methods.

Comment: I do not think what you are trying to do is possible. If you are trying to execute custom code when that Exception is thrown, just use try-catch blocks and call your custom method in the catch.

Comment: I have tried everything but I don't know which code snippet is causing this exception. Because the library calls internally another methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a **ClassException** with the same package as the library and put it before in the classpath (e.g in a jar starting with _).

But, you won't get any further information since the exception will be thrown as it's being thrown now.

You could try decompiling the code (if the license allows you) and using the debugger to go step by step.

Answer (score 0):

try this

1. write your own `ClassException.java`
2. compile it to produce a `ClassException.class` file
3. swap with the original `ClassException.class` file